Change of coordinates in a regular surface $S$.
I'm quite confused in the following situation:
Suppose that $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is a regular surface. Let $U_1$ and $U_2$ be open sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and consider the pair of parameterizations for $S$:
$X: U_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, given by $X(u,v) = (x(u,v), y(u,v), z(u,v))$
$Y: U_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, given by $Y(\bar{u},\bar{v}) = (x(\bar{u},\bar{v}), y(\bar{u},\bar{v}), z(\bar{u},\bar{v}))$
Suppose $W = X(U_1) \cap Y(U_2) \neq \emptyset$.
We know that the transition map (change of coordinates) $(X^{-1} \circ Y): Y^{-1}(W) \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow X^{-1}(W) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is a diffeomorphism and is given by $(X^{-1} \circ Y)(\bar{u},\bar{v}) = (u(\bar{u},\bar{v}),v(\bar{u},\bar{v}))$.
Similarly, the transition map $(Y^{-1} \circ X): X^{-1}(W) \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow Y^{-1}(W) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is a diffeomorphism given by $(Y^{-1} \circ X)(u,v) = (\bar{u}(u,v),\bar{v}(u,v))$.
Now, given $p \in W$, we can consider the tangent plane to $p$, denoted by $T_p M$, which is a 2-dimensional vector space that we can identify with $\mathbb{R}^2$. Moreover, denoting $X_u, X_v$ as the partial derivatives of $X$ with respect to $u$ and $v$ respectively, we know that $ \{ X_u, X_v \} $ forms a basis for $T_p M$, where $X_u = (x_u, y_u, z_u)$ and $X_v = (x_v, y_v, z_v)$.
Similarly, considering the partial derivatives $Y_{\bar{u}}, Y_{\bar{v}}$, we know that $\{ Y_{\bar{u}}, Y_{\bar{v}} \}$ is also a basis for $T_p M$, where $Y_{\bar{u}} = (x_{\bar{u}}, y_{\bar{u}}, z_{\bar{u}})$ and $Y_{\bar{v}} = (x_{\bar{v}}, y_{\bar{v}}, z_{\bar{v}})$.
Suppose we want to obtain the vectors $Y_{\bar{u}}$ and $Y_{\bar{v}}$ in terms of the basis $\{ X_u, X_v \}$. To do this, we need to calculate the Jacobian matrix of the transition map $X^{-1} \circ Y$, which is given by:
$$\dfrac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(\bar{u},\bar{v})} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \bar{u}} & \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \bar{v}} \\
\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial \bar{u}} & \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial \bar{v}}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
According to Do Carmo's book, we obtain:
\begin{equation}Y_{\bar{u}} = X_u \frac{\partial u}{\partial \bar{u}} + X_v \frac{\partial v}{\partial \bar{u}}\end{equation}
\begin{equation}Y_{\bar{v}} = X_u \frac{\partial u}{\partial \bar{v}} + X_v \frac{\partial v}{\partial \bar{v}} \end{equation}
But these two equations are not making any sense to me. Shouldn't it be necessary to perform the calculation $Y_{\bar{u}} = \frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(\bar{u},\bar{v})} \cdot [X_u]$? Where $[X_u]$ represents the column matrix with the coordinates of the vector $X_u$. But this doesn't make sense, because the matrix $\dfrac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(\bar{u},\bar{v})}$ is $2 \times 2 $ and $X_u$ has 3 coordinates.
Could someone please explain to me where I am going wrong?

If $W$ is $3$-dimensional, how is its tangent space one dimension less?

Call $C=X^{-1}\circ Y$, then $Y=X\circ C$ and the derivatives are
connected as
$$JY_p=JX_{C(p)}\ JC_p,$$
by the chain's rule.
Using the canonical basis you can get
$$JY_pe_1=JX_{C(p)}\ JC_pe_1,$$
and that $JC$ is your $\dfrac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(\tilde u,\tilde v)}$.
Then $JC_pe_1=\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \tilde u}e_1+\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \tilde v}e_2$.
So
\begin{eqnarray*}
Y_{\tilde u}&=&JX_{C(p)}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial \tilde u}e_1+\frac{\partial u}{\partial \tilde v}e_2\right),\\
&=&\frac{\partial u}{\partial \tilde u}JX_{C(p)}e_1+\frac{\partial u}{\partial \tilde v}JX_{C(p)}e_2,\\
&=&\frac{\partial u}{\partial \tilde u}X_u+\frac{\partial u}{\partial \tilde v}X_v.\qquad (1)
\end{eqnarray*}
Similarly the other:
$$Y_{\tilde v}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial \tilde u}X_u+\frac{\partial v}{\partial \tilde v}X_v\qquad (2).$$
Those equations, (1) and (2), explain which is the change of basis' matrix in the tangent space.

Thanks for your help.

glad to be useful
